# Binding ComboBox TwoWay to Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, combobox

I'm trying to get my TwoWay-Binding to work.

These ComboBoxes should bind themselve (TwoWay) to their property in the VM:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="_cmbCatT1" Margin="5,1,5,10" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding MVM.CategoryLinkCollection}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Category.Name" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding MVM.SelectedTier1, Mode=TwoWay}" 
          SelectedValuePath="Category"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="_cmbCatT2" Margin="5,1,5,10" 
          DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=_cmbCatT1}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryLinkCollection}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Category.Name" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding MVM.SelectedTier2, ElementName=_vManipulation, Mode=TwoWay}" 
          SelectedValuePath="Category"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="_cmbCatT3" Margin="5,1,5,10" 
          DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=_cmbCatT2}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryLinkCollection}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Category.Name" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding MVM.SelectedTier3, ElementName=_vManipulation, Mode=TwoWay}" 
          SelectedValuePath="Category"/>
```

VM:

```
private string selectedName;
public string SelectedName {
    get {
        return this.selectedName;
    }
    set {
        this.selectedName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedName");
    }
}
private string selectedDescription;
public string SelectedDescription {
    get {
        return this.selectedDescription;
    }
    set {
        this.selectedDescription = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedDescription");
    }
}
private string selectedRemark;
public string SelectedRemark {
    get {
        return this.selectedRemark;
    }
    set {
        this.selectedRemark = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedRemark");
    }
}
private string selectedValue; 
public string SelectedValue {
    get {
        return this.selectedValue;
    }
    set {
        this.selectedValue = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedValue");
    }
}
private Model.Room selectedRoom;
public Model.Room SelectedRoom {
    get {
        return this.selectedRoom;
    }
    set {
        this.selectedRoom = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedRoom");
    }
}
private Model.Locker selectedLocker;
public Model.Locker SelectedLocker {
    get {
        return this.selectedLocker;
    }
    set {
        this.selectedLocker = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedLocker");
    }
}
private Model.Category selectedTier1;
public Model.Category SelectedTier1 {
    get {
        return this.selectedTier1;
    }
    set {
        this.selectedTier1 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTier1");
    }
}
private Model.Category selectedTier2;
public Model.Category SelectedTier2 {
    get {
        return this.selectedTier2;
    }
    set {
        this.selectedTier2 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTier2");
    }
}
private Model.Category selectedTier3;
public Model.Category SelectedTier3 {
    get {
        return this.selectedTier3;
    }
    set {
        this.selectedTier3 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTier3");
    }
}
private Model.Manufacturer selectedManufacturer;
public Model.Manufacturer SelectedManufacturer {
    get {
        return this.selectedManufacturer;
    }
    set {
        this.selectedManufacturer = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedManufacturer");
    }
}
```

Notice that the DataType of the ItemsSource is "CategoryLinkCollection" which Contains a "Category"-Property and an Obs.Collection of "CategoryLinkCollection". Through the SelectedValuePath the "Category" gets "saved" in the Property in the VM.

As long as I select an Item in the ComboBox everything just works fine but
when I set the VM-Properties manually the ComboBoxes won't preselect the Item from the ItemsSource which contains the defined Category. Normal string values just work finde (Textboxes)

I assume it will never work because of the differen types (ComboBox = CategoryLinkCollection with ValuePath to Category, Property = Category) but maybe some of you could prove me wrong. If you need more informations let me know.

**Update 1:**

I just remembered that the main reason should be somewhere else because the Model "Manufacturer" got no wrapper - so the ItemsSource contains a Collection of the same data type as the property is.

XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="_cmbManufacturer" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding MVM.ManufacturerCollection}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding MVM.SelectedManufacturer, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

VM:
see above.

**Update 2:**

At first please get away from that crappy Categorys and head over to the Manufacturer mentioned in Update 1 because it's the same issue but much easier to get in.

I now checked the SelectedManufacturer-Property after setting it manually just in case there would be some problems while setting it.
The SelectedManufacturer-Property contains a Manufacturer (not null) but still the UI does not get updated.

**Update 3:**

I've got the following output out of the Output-Window after using the diagnostics NS:

> System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=43478430): Default mode resolved to TwoWay
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=43478430): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=43478430): Attach to System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox.SelectedItem (hash=10372298)
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=43478430): Resolving source
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=43478430): Found data context element: ComboBox (hash=10372298) (OK)
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=43478430): Activate with root item Manipulation (hash=64100268)
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 107 : BindingExpression (hash=43478430):   At level 0 using cached accessor for Manipulation.MVM: RuntimePropertyInfo(MVM)
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=43478430): Replace item at level 0 with Manipulation (hash=64100268), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(MVM)
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=43478430): GetValue at level 0 from Manipulation (hash=64100268) using RuntimePropertyInfo(MVM): ManipulationViewModel (hash=11088040)
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=43478430):   At level 1 - for ManipulationViewModel.SelectedManufacturer found accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(SelectedManufacturer)
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=43478430): Replace item at level 1 with ManipulationViewModel (hash=11088040), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(SelectedManufacturer)
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=43478430): GetValue at level 1 from ManipulationViewModel (hash=11088040) using RuntimePropertyInfo(SelectedManufacturer): Manufacturer (hash=14500136)
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=43478430): TransferValue - got raw value Manufacturer (hash=14500136)
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 84 : BindingExpression (hash=43478430): TransferValue - implicit converter produced Manufacturer (hash=14500136)
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=43478430): TransferValue - using final value Manufacturer (hash=14500136)

**Update 4:**

Manufacturer Class:

```
public class Manufacturer : Base.SqlBase {
    public Manufacturer(int id, string name) {
        this.SqlID = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

SqlBase Class:

```
public abstract class SqlBase : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public int SqlID { get; set; }
    private string _name;
    public string Name {
        get {
            return _name;
        }
        protected set {
            this._name = value;
            PropertyChangedHandler("Name");
        }
    }

    public void SetId(int id) {
        this.SqlID = id;
        PropertyChangedHandler("SqlID");
    }

    private void PropertyChangedHandler(string propertyName) {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler temp = PropertyChanged;
        if (temp != null) {
            temp(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Entity Class:

```
public class Entity : Base.SqlBase {

    public string Description { get; private set; }
    public string Remark { get; private set; }
    public int Value { get; private set; }
    public Model.CategoryWrapper Categories { get; private set; }
    public Model.Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; private set; }
    public Model.Locker Locker { get; private set; }

    public Entity(string name, string desc, string remark, int value, Model.CategoryWrapper cat, Model.Manufacturer manuf, Model.Locker locker) {           
        this.Name = name;
        this.Description = desc;
        this.Remark = remark;
        this.Value = value;
        this.Categories = cat;
        this.Manufacturer = manuf;
        this.Locker = locker;
    }

    public Entity(int id, string name, string desc, string remark, int value, Model.CategoryWrapper cat, Model.Manufacturer manuf, Model.Locker locker) {
        this.SqlID = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Description = desc;
        this.Remark = remark;
        this.Value = value;
        this.Categories = cat;
        this.Manufacturer = manuf;
        this.Locker = locker;
    }
}
```

I get the SelectedItem of a GridView (Type: Entity) and hand it over to my Manipulation-View which instantiates it's ViewModel. In this ViewModel the Entity gets divided into it's parts (eg. Manufacturer) and the properties (eg. SelectedManufacturer) get set. All these steps get executed **before** the View gets built (before Initializecomponent). I thought in this way the View has to get the selected values when initialised - or am I wrong?

**Update 5:**

I really don't know why but when setting a Manufacturer when the Window is initialising the PropertyChanged-Property of the Manufacturer object is null - when I set the Manufacturer through selecting an item the Property is not null.

Comment: Have your tried using a Converter? I am not 100% sure, but since you are using missmatched types this might be the issue.

Comment: I just remembered that "Manufacturer" is the same type (except Collection). I'll just update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I've solved the mystery.

**Explanation:**

The "Manipulation"- View, which should pre-select the ComboBox-Value given by the Entity will receive it's own instance of the ObservableCollection - but the Manufacturer-Object gets passed to that form - so it's not contained in the Collection.

**Solution:**

Overriding the Equals-Method to check the SQLID Property rather than the default method to determine equality solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use the update source trigger property in your binding and set it to PropertyChanged:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="_cmbManufacturer" ItemsSource="{Binding MVM.ManufacturerCollection}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding MVM.SelectedManufacturer, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: Both, setting the UpdateSourceTrigger and using the same data type didnt solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Howsit Chill-X, Do I understand correctly that the core issue is that you want  the Combo boxes to reflect the changed selection when you update your viewModel? If so, here's a watered down version of how you can do that.

Important things to note (Binding the selected item to another property called **SelectedCategory**. When you change **SelectedCategory** in the VM, the UI will change and if you select a new item in the combo box, the **SelectedCategory** property will be updated.

Here's the View Model:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Category> _categoryLinkCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<Category> CategoryLinkCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return this._categoryLinkCollection;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._categoryLinkCollection)
            {
                this._categoryLinkCollection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CategoryLinkCollection");
            }
        }
    }

    private Category _selectedCategory;
    public Category SelectedCategory
    {
        get
        {
            return this._selectedCategory;
        }
        set
        {
            this._selectedCategory = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCategory");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the xaml:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryLinkCollection, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

I've simply used the code behind page to add dummy data to the collection (on window_loaded and the button click to show you can update the VM property and UI updates.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set the View's DataContext to our ViewModel
        var vm = new ViewModel();
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Populate Category Collection with dummy data.
        var vm = ((ViewModel)this.DataContext);
        vm.CategoryLinkCollection = new ObservableCollection<Category>()
        {
            new Category("Cat 1"),
            new Category("Cat 2"),
            new Category("Cat 3"),
            new Category("Cat 4"),
            new Category("Cat 5"),
            new Category("Cat 6"),
        };
        vm.SelectedCategory = vm.CategoryLinkCollection[0];
    }

    private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var vm = ((ViewModel)this.DataContext);
        vm.SelectedCategory = vm.CategoryLinkCollection[3];
    }
}
```

Now you've got a ComboBox which updates from VM and from UI.

Comment: The only difference I can see is the additional Mode in "ItemsSource" or am I wrong? Let's get away from that Categorys as they are a little bit more difficult that they seem. Let's take that Manufacturer I mentioned in my Update. When I select a new Manufacturer through the ComboBox everything works fine - OneWay = checked. But when I change the SelectedManufacturer-Property manually to another Manufacturer the UI does not get updated (ComboBox is empty). (The SelectedManufacturer is an Item which is Contained in the ManufacturerCollection, just to mention it).

Comment: The Manufacturer ComboBox looks correct. I would check the following:
1) Put a breakpoint on the set of the SelectedManufacturer-Property. When you update the ComBox via the UI, does the breakpoint get hit?
2) When you set the SelectedManufacturer-Property from code behind / VM, does it call the _OnPropertyChanged_ with the correctly spelt property name?
3) Is your ManufacturerCollection an _ObservableCollection_?
4) If all of the above are correct, I would put a breakpoint in the _OnPropertyChanged_ method and see if actually invokes calls the _PropertyChanged_ event.

Comment: Do you set the dataContext of your view to your VM? E.g. in the Code behind Window_Loaded, put a breakpoint and add a watch / quick watch to see what _this.DataContext_ is. If it's null, then in the Window_Loaded method add _this.DataContext = myVMinstance;_ and see if PropertyChanged now has a value. myVMinstance would be an instance of your ViewModel class.

Comment: Ty dude but the mystery is solved already. The problem was caused by the equality-check - overriding the Equals-Method solved it. By the way, in my opinion the Inline-XAML-Datasource definition is a better practice than defining it in the code behind :)

Comment: Fantastic, well done! And yes I agree with you, defining the Context in the code-behind was merely for debugging purposes. Cheers